# Sending XML in Curl PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

I currently send my form data as normal Post.
I would like to send it as XML .

Current format : name=max
Format i need : max

Here is my current code :

```
// This is the data to POST to the form. The KEY of the array is the name of the field. The value is the value posted.
$data_to_post = array();
$data_to_post['title'] = '$title';
$data_to_post['first_name'] = '$first_name';
$data_to_post['surname'] = '$surname';
$data_to_post['email'] = '$email';
$data_to_post['dob'] = '$dob';

// Initialize cURL
$curl = curl_init();

// Set the options
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $form_url);

// This sets the number of fields to post
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, sizeof($data_to_post));

// This is the fields to post in the form of an array.
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_to_post);

//execute the post
$result = curl_exec($curl);

//close the connection
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to convert your array into xml data. Reffer link for convert array into xml [array to xml conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml)

Now you have to send data using following code

```
$input_xml = ''; //XML Data 
$url=''; // URL


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                "xmlRequest=" . $input_xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a XML. You must send your XML string in a POST var

```
$data_to_post = array();
$data_to_post['xml'] = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data_to_post>
<title><![CDATA['.$title']]><title>
<first_name><![CDATA['.$first_name']]><first_name>
<surname><![CDATA['.$surname']]><surname>
<email><![CDATA['.$email']]><email>
<dob><![CDATA['.$dob']]><dob>
</data_to_post>'
```