# given error when I use CurlExec in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I am new in laravel, my code is

```
$xmldata = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SmartReportRequest version="1.00">
    <UDIParameter>
        <!-- <Parameter key="HTTPBizID">' . $HTTPBizID . '</Parameter>-->
        <Parameter key="UDIAuthToken">' . $udi_token . '</Parameter>
        <Parameter key="ReportID">1</Parameter>
        <!--<Parameter key="GroupDateType">RowDateRangeLast200Orders</Parameter>-->
        <Parameter key="FromDate">' . $date_from . '</Parameter>
        <Parameter key="ToDate">' . $date_to . '</Parameter>
    </UDIParameter>
</SmartReportRequest>';

//echo $xmldata; exit;


            $result = $this->CurlExec($xmldata, 2);

            $result_xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

when I using this code then given error is :

BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 107:
Method [CurlExec] does not exist. like [image]

please give me suggestion how to fix this ? I was trying 
https://github.com/ixudra/curl but didn't get solution.
thanks!

Comment: what is `$this` in this context? Clearly it does not have the method CurlExec

Comment: `$this` is only to be used in the current class. You'll have to make the call to `CurlExec` with whatever you named the instance of `new \Ixudra\Curl\CurlService();` too

Comment: @Naik sir $this is represent controller.

Comment: @isThisJavascript I try but given error is 'Call to undefined method Ixudra\Curl\CurlService::CurlExec()'

Comment: Where are you getting `CurlExec()` from? I don't believe that exists in https://github.com/ixudra/curl, Laravel or PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, it seems you want to send some XML via CURL but you haven't even specified an endpoint or URL to send this data to.

`CurlExec()` is not a valid method anywhere I can see, just seems a little similar to php's `curl_exec()` which is not used the way you are trying to use it.

Here is an example of how to send the xml to an endpoint as post data using **Ixudra\Curl** but again I have no idea the requirements of your endpoint or how they expect data.

```
// Top of the file
use Ixudra\Curl\Facades\Curl;

// In your function below $xmldata definition
$response = Curl::to('URL OF ENDPOINT HERE')
    ->withData(['xml' => $xmldata])
    ->post();
```

See this post on information on how to send xml data using normal PHP and not Ixudra Curl. [Sending XML in Curl PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751162/sending-xml-in-curl-php)

Comment: please check my code on upper, I haven't url using token  so please give me suggestion...